# MSP430 ADC least significant bits always 1

Tags: microcontroller, adc, analog, msp430

I have an [MSP430F2618](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontroller/16-bit_msp430/overview.page?DCMP=MCU_other&HQS=msp430) with built in 12-bit ADC, but for some reason the values it returns always end with the 2 least significant bits set to 1, except when it zeroes out. In other words, the counts are always of the form 0x##3, 0x##7, 0x##B, or 0x##F. Am I missing something in my initialization that magically turns my 12bit ADC into a 10bit? Could there be some transient voltage that just happens to always saturate the sampling circuit for the least significant bits? Any suggestions?

```
  P6SEL |= 0x01;                            // P6.0,P6.1-ADC option select
  ADC12CTL0 = SHT0_8 + ADC12ON + MSC;       // Set sampling time, turn on ADC12 (256 ADC12CLK cycles, ADCON, Multiple sample and conversion)
  ADC12CTL1 = SHP + CONSEQ_1;                 // Use sampling timer (SAMPCON signal is sourced from the sampling timer, Sequence-of-channels conversion sequence mode)
  ADC12MCTL0 = SREF_6 + INCH_0 + EOS;             //inch (Input channel) assigns channel to this memory location, (Reference: VR+ =VeREF+ and VR- = VREF-), end of sequence
  ADC12IE = 0x01;                           // Enable interrupt
  ADC12CTL0 |= ENC;                         // Conversion enabled
```

Comment: What's the full part number of the device?

Comment: Full part number: MSP430f2618

Comment: Do you have the reference pins adequately decoupled? The reference manual suggests a 10uF in parallel with a 100nF, to quote p.563: `Approximately 200 µA is required from any reference used by the ADC12 while the two LSBs
are being resolved during a conversion. A parallel combination of 10-µF and 0.1-µF
capacitors is recommended for any reference as shown in Figure 23-11.`

Comment: @Oli Good find, investigating. I'll post an answer if that turns out to be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Oli was right. I had no caps on my VRef and the supply wasn't able to source 200uA of transient current for the last 2 bits of conversion.

Adding 10uF across VRef+ and VRef- solved the problem.